# How to include only specific jar from libs into gradle build?

Tags: java, gradle, web-applications, jar, build.gradle

I'm using `gradle V4.10.2` and `eclipse` for building `WAR` files. I have some common `JAR` files for all the wars. I need them to use only during compile time and need to exclude them while building into `WAR` file. Also I don't want to exclude all the `JAR`s file.

I've put all the JARs in `libs` folder. In `build.gradle`, I have specified only the JARs to be included. Since the exclude list is bigger then include list of JARs I'm not using `exclude`

```
war {
    rootSpec.include("**/test.jar")
}
```

The above results the `WAR` file without `META-INF` folder. Hence, webapp is not started. I have tried adding the libs as `reference lib` in `eclipse` but that results in compilation error.

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details
```

So I have to include all the JARs in libs folder and then need to use only required JARs in the WAR built. How to include only specific JARs into build?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management

Comment: You shouldn't be using lib dirs, it's 2019 (and you're not a caveman building with ant!) You should be using dependencies from a repository which can participate in dependency resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend reading about [building Java projects with Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/building_java_projects.html) and in particular the part about [web applications](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:building_java_webapps)

In short you should add the JARs needed for compilation only to the `compileOnly` configuration and the JARs needed for compilation *and* at runtime in the `implementation` configuration.
Gradle will then use all of them for compilation and only include the ones in `implementation` when packaging the WAR.

While you can do that by selecting them from your `libs` folder, I strongly recommend moving to libraries and its metadata sourced from a repository, private or public, so that the dependency management is done for you.